# Centralized local Maven repository for Team

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-3, local

Our team of developers uses Maven for building software. We have Maven local repository on our computers. The problem is that sometimes builds made from two different developer differ, because the built packages include different version of included dependencies.

This happens when version tag is not mentioned in POM.xml file for dependencies. For example:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mylib-group</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib-artifact</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In this case Maven gets the newest library installed locally.

To avoid this problem We installed Maven on one computer (we call Build server) and all members of our team make build on that computer.

Is there any better solution for this case?

How can I have centralized Maven local ?

Comment: A better solution is to use an organization-level artifact repository like Nexus or Artifactory and have all developers publish to it. Even better, all artifact versions that have to be dependable should be built on a CI server, such that it's OK for every developer to test with the build from their own branch, installing locally.

Comment: Absolutely aggree with @ernest_k, also you should explicitly declare the versions of your dependencies. If you need a newer one for local development, simply change it and once your done, commit the changed version to remote VCS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you have a dependency like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mylib-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib-artifact</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Maven will *not* take the latest version, but the one defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` section. So you get the same results on every computer (unless you have SNAPSHOT versions which might differ).

Having said that: Having a build server is generally a good idea for having a stable environment for builds.

Addendum: You can *not* share a Maven local repository. This repository is not thread safe and running two builds at the same time on the same local repository can have strange effects (I speak from experience).